# Detect empty file upload array

Tags: php, if-statement, file-upload, foreach

When using the code below to "Update" an existing record in the database, I have tried several ways (at least 6) to adjust this script so that it should only write the stored path to the image IF a new image was selected for upload. Every method I have tried passes syntax check but i get the same results no matter what, each time the script runs, all 5 "image" rows in the selected database record are written over as BLANK regardless of whether i chose one, multiple or no files in the submission form. This for/script combo works perfect as intended when CREATING A NEW record, but is proving a lot more difficult when using it to update existing record. how do i write this so that only the file upload fields that are presented with a new file are written to the database, to the appropriate row.

**FORM FOR UPDATE OF IMAGES IF ANY.**

```
<div style="width:98%">Product Image 1:<input type="file" name="prodi[]" />
<?php if (!$row['image1']=="") {echo "<a href='#afrow2' onclick=\"window.open('$row[image1]','_blank','toolbar=yes, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, top=300, left=300, width=400, height=400'); \"> Current Image</a>";} ?>
</div>
<div style="width:98%">Product Image 2:<input type="file" name="prodi[]" />
<?php if (!$row['image2']=="") {echo "<a href='#afrow2' onclick=\"window.open('$row[image2]','_blank','toolbar=yes, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, top=300, left=300, width=400, height=400'); \"> Current Image</a>";} ?>
</div>
<div style="width:98%">Product Image 3:<input type="file" name="prodi[]" />
<?php if (!$row['image3']=="") {echo "<a href='#afrow2' onclick=\"window.open('$row[image3]','_blank','toolbar=yes, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, top=300, left=300, width=400, height=400'); \"> Current Image</a>";} ?>
</div>
<div style="width:98%">Product Image 4:<input type="file" name="prodi[]" />
<?php if (!$row['image4']=="") {echo "<a href='#afrow2' onclick=\"window.open('$row[image4]','_blank','toolbar=yes, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, top=300, left=300, width=400, height=400'); \"> Current Image</a>";} ?>
</div>
<div style="width:98%">Product Image 5:<input type="file" name="prodi[]" />
<?php if (!$row['image5']=="") {echo "<a href='#afrow2' onclick=\"window.open('$row[image5]','_blank','toolbar=yes, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, top=300, left=300, width=400, height=400'); \"> Current Image</a>";} ?>
</div>
```

**IMAGE UPLOAD / HANDLER SCRIPT**

```
$inum=0;
$image1="";
$image2="";
$image3="";
$image4="";
$image5="";

foreach ($_FILES["prodi"]["error"] as $key => $error)
{
    if ($error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        $tmp_name = $_FILES["prodi"]["tmp_name"][$key];
        $name = $_FILES["prodi"]["name"][$key];
        $type = $_FILES["prodi"] ["type"] [$key];
        if ($type=="image/jpg" OR $type=="image/jpeg" OR $type=="image/pjpeg" OR $type=="image/png")
        {move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "../images/item-images/$name");$ipath=$domain."/images/item-images/".$name;
        $inum++;
        $i="image".$inum;
        $$i=$ipath;
    }
                                 }
}
if (!$image1=""){mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE rdata SET image1='$image1' WHERE sku=$_POST[itmSku]");}
if (!$image2=""){mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE rdata SET image2='$image2' WHERE sku=$_POST[itmSku]");}
if (!$image3=""){mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE rdata SET image3='$image3' WHERE sku=$_POST[itmSku]");}
if (!$image4=""){mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE rdata SET image4='$image4' WHERE sku=$_POST[itmSku]");}
if (!$image5=""){mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE rdata SET image5='$image5' WHERE sku=$_POST[itmSku]");}
```

Comment: maybe you want to use `UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE`?

Comment: @DrixsonOseña I did/have considered that, but not sure where to place it in the code as I have tried several variations of "limiting"/"filtering" the code with no success... (of course no error message either.), if you would advise on where you would place it in the code that would be of great help at this point. Also, with the if (error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) in place... wouldn't a empty file submission in the array already produce "UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE" anyways, therefor the IF test would be FALSE ?

Comment: try this `if ($error === UPLOAD_ERR_OK)` or `if ($error == 1)`

Comment: @DrixsonOseña `if ($error === UPLOAD_ERR_OK or $error == 1)` had same result

Comment: you know that  `UPLOAD_ERR_OK` means that if your upload has no problem right? then add put `else` in your statement if there's an error in uploading